# Uploading releasenotes text to GitHub using GitHub API fails sometimes

Tags: git, github, github-api

I have a problem uploading releasenotes for an existing tag, if the tag was just created (https://github.com/tschulte/gradle-semantic-release-plugin/issues/3). My code does first create an annotated tag and pushes it. Directly after that, it uses the GitHub API to set the body of the just created release. This does fail often -- less often on a new repository with few commits, more often, if the repository contains more commits.

I used the following bash script to reproduce this behaviour

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

user=tschulte
repo=github-releasetest

version="$1"
tag="v$version"

git tag $tag -m "Release of $version"
git push origin "$tag"

curl -i -X POST -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" -H "Authorization: token $GH_TOKEN" \
    "https://api.github.com/repos/$user/$repo/releases" \
    -d "{\"tag_name\": \"$tag\", \"body\": \"# Changelog of $version\"}"
```

I ran the script in a loop

```
export GH_TOKEN=...
for v in {61..100}; do ./issue3 $v; done
```

The result was, that not all releases where uploaded. The ones that could not be uploaded had following returned by the GitHub API (with HTTP status code 422):

```
{
    "message":"Validation Failed",
    "errors":[
        {
            "resource":"Release",
            "code":"custom",
            "message":"Published releases must have a valid tag"
        }
    ],
    "documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#create-a-release"
}
```

I know I could fix my code by not using `git tag` and `git push` and instead using the GitHub API to also create the tag and not just to set the releasenotes text. But the upload of the releasenotes is an addon to the existing behaviour, which I don't want to change.

Is there anything else I can do? Or is this a bug in the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API to create a release does support multiple use cases:

- Create a tag and release (using the current master or a given committish) and set it's body text
- Create a release using an existing tag

But the switch which version to use is just whether or not the tag exists already. If the tag was just created, the API might not be aware of that yet. To be sure, check if the tag exists using the API after the tag is pushed and before creating the release. The following script does work

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

user=tschulte
repo=github-releasetest

version="$1"
tag="v$version"

git tag $tag -m "Release of $version"
git push origin "$tag"

echo "checking existence of tag $tag using API"
while [ "$(curl -s -w "%{http_code}" -H "Authorization: token $GH_TOKEN" "https://api.github.com/repos/$user/$repo/git/refs/tags/$tag" -o /dev/null)" -ne "200" ]
do
    echo "API does not know tag -- retrying"
done
echo "API knows tag"

if [ "$(curl -s -w "%{http_code}" -X POST -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" -H "Authorization: token $GH_TOKEN" \
    "https://api.github.com/repos/$user/$repo/releases" \
    -d "{\"tag_name\": \"$tag\", \"body\": \"# Changelog of $version\"}" -o /dev/null)" == "201" ]
then
    echo "Release uploaded successfully"
else
    echo "Release could not be uploaded"
    exit 1
fi
```

Interestingly, sometimes the API seems to take some time before it knows the tag:

```
Counting objects: 1, done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 171 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:tschulte/github-releasetest.git
 * [new tag]         v238 -> v238
checking existence of tag v238 using API
API does not know tag -- retrying
API does not know tag -- retrying
API does not know tag -- retrying
API does not know tag -- retrying
API does not know tag -- retrying
API knows tag
Release uploaded successfully
```